# The probability that $n$ tosses produce no sequence of $HHH$

Tags: probability, proof-explanation

[image]

(Feller Vol.1, P.278) I don't understand how the author derive the equation, which I highlight with the purple line. The author says that "the event that $n$ trials produce no sequence $HHH$ can occur only when the trials begin with $T$, $HT$, or $HHT$." I don't understand this statement, and I would appreciate if you add some details.

Comment: Consider the case where the first toss is a tail. Now, the probability that a sequence $HHH$ appears in the $n$ tosses is same that probability appearing in the next $n - 1$ tosses since the first toss was a tail. But the probability that $HHH$ appears in $n- 1$ tosses is $q_{n-1}$ which should give you the first term. The half comes from the fact that the first toss was a tail. Can you extrapolate this logic for the cases when the first two tosses are $HT$ and the first three are $HHT$?

Comment: @sudeep5221 Thanks. I don't know why I couldn't see before.